Next.js TypeError: a.default.detectStore(...) is undefined
I just started working on a Next.js App. And now I am encountering this error whenever I call the page (hosted locally with npm run dev:
TypeError: a.default.detectStore(...) is undefined

u                 moz-extension://e51e5a88-36af-4f98-b63a-0d30c0512868/h1-check.js:1
1337              moz-extension://e51e5a88-36af-4f98-b63a-0d30c0512868/h1-check.js:1
n                 moz-extension://e51e5a88-36af-4f98-b63a-0d30c0512868/h1-check.js:1
<anonym>          moz-extension://e51e5a88-36af-4f98-b63a-0d30c0512868/h1-check.js:1
<anonym>          moz-extension://e51e5a88-36af-4f98-b63a-0d30c0512868/h1-check.js:1
inject            resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.sys.mjs:585
injectInto        resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.sys.mjs:458
AsyncFunctionNext self-hosted:799

I just realized the error occurs on Firefox and apparently not on Safari.
I have created the next app from an example for next with docker. I'm not sure if the error occured from the beginning because I did not check the console until I had worked on it quite a bit.
I found the following post on Reddit but there is no reason why the solution there should apply to my case (in my opinion)
And there was a question on stackoverflow but it was closed as the person asking did not provide enough information.
I wondered if it had something to do with the  tags I added to my page, just because it says a... is undefined. But the error occurs even on the default next.js index page that was given in the example.

the problem might be plugin or extension installed in Firefox.
E.g. check this article out, hopefully it will be helpful.
From this comment by lokidecat to https://webcompat.com/issues/131759 -

It was my Honey plug-in for my browser that was giving me that error, personally. I removed the plug-in and the error is gone.

